# What is the simplest way to show that $x\log(1+\frac{a}{x})$ is an increasing function of $x$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convex-analysis

How to show that $x\log(1+\frac{a}{x})$ is an increasing function of $x$ for non-negative values of $x$? Actually its derivative is $$\log\left(1+\frac{a}{x}\right)-\frac{a}{a+x}$$ ($a$ is positive) where we can see that the second term is negative> so how to show that the derivative of $x\log(1+\frac{a}{x})$ is positive? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to look at the second derivative

Comment: Is $a$ nonnegative as aswell?

Comment: The fact that there seems to be the limit definition of $e^a$ in there might be important

Comment: No $a$ is positive

Comment: @AndrewLi would you please that definition?

Comment: A very useful fact about the $\log$ function is that $\log(1+y) \leq y$ for all $y>-1$. It seems that can be used to evaluate your derivative.

Comment: @Patrick the second derivative is always negative and is equal to $$-\frac{a^2}{x(a+x)^2}$$. How to proceed further? I am not sure how to cater for all the possible values of $a$? Please guide me on this

Comment: You knoe the second derivative is always negative so first derivative is decreasing. Calculate the limit as x tends to infinity of the first derivative. You will get the limit is positive. Thus the derivstive is always positive

Comment: @Patrick you are absolutely right. I can understand it for finite values of $a$ but will it be true for $a=\infty$ also?

Comment: I don't understand how you define the function for a infinity. It doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @Patrick wouldn't it come out to be zero, so nonnegative, but not positive?

Comment: @Patrick Ok maybe i have to add some line so that $a$ is always finite

Comment: @Frank Moses I think $a$ would have to be finite since it is a constant.

Comment: @Tyberius didn't calculate the limit myself as i'm on my phone. If the limit is zero, you can still argue the the derivative is non zero. If it's zero at some point x it has to be zero at all points t>x which cannot be true

Comment: @Patrick the limit of the first derivative as $x\to \infty$ is not positive. It is zero

Comment: @Patrck but if we limit the values of $x$ to a certain finite positive value then using your comment we can say that the derivative is always positive uptill that finite value of $x$.

Comment: @Frank Moses I think this gets at the subtle point of increasing vs strictly increasing. Strictly increasing means that the derivative is always positive over some interval, while increasing just means it is nonnegative, so this should still satisfy your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $g(u) = (1 + u)\log(1 + u) - u$ is increasing for $u > 0$. Indeed, 
$$
g^{\prime}(u) = \log(1 + u) + \dfrac{1 + u}{1 + u} - 1 = \log(1 + u) \geq 0 \quad \text{to} \quad u \geq 0   
$$
But, $g(0) = 0$. Thus, $g(u) > g(0) = 0$ if $u > 0$ or
$$
(1 + u)\log(1 + u) > u \quad \Rightarrow \quad \log(1 + u) - \dfrac{u}{1 + u} > 0
$$ 
for $u > 0$. For $u = a/x$, we have
$$
\log\biggl(1 + \dfrac{a}{x}\biggr) - \dfrac{a/x}{1 + a/x} > 0 \quad \Rightarrow 
$$
$$
f^{\prime}(x) = \log\biggl(1 + \dfrac{a}{x}\biggr) - \dfrac{a}{a + x} > 0 \quad \Rightarrow
$$
$f$ increasing.

Answer (score 4):

I think the most parsimonious way to do this is via the integral representation of the logarithm. To start, note that
$$\begin{split}\frac{\ln(1+t)}{t}&=\frac{1}{t}\int_1^{1+t}\frac{\mathrm{d}t'}{t'}\\
&=\frac{1}{t}\int_0^{t}\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{1+u}\\
&=\int_0^{1}\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{1+tv}\text{.}
\end{split}$$

Substitute $t\leftarrow a/x$ and multiply both sides by $a$. Then
$$x\ln(1+a/x)=\int_0^{1}\frac{ax\mathrm{d}v}{x+av}$$

so
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(x\ln(1+a/x)\right)=\int_0^{1}\frac{a^2v\mathrm{d}v}{(x+av)^2}$$
which is manifestly positive.

Comment: Thank you great explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Using the integral definition of $\log$,

$\begin{array}\\
(x\log(1+\dfrac{a}{x}))'
&=\log\left(1+\frac{a}{x}\right)-\dfrac{a}{a+x}\\
&=\int_1^{1+\frac{a}{x}}\dfrac{dt}{t}-\dfrac{a}{a+x}\\
&=\int_0^{\frac{a}{x}}\dfrac{dt}{1+t}-\dfrac{a}{a+x}\\
&=\int_0^{\frac{a}{x}}\dfrac{dt}{1+t}-\dfrac{a/x}{1+a/x}\\
&=\int_0^{\frac{a}{x}}\left(\dfrac{1}{1+t}-\dfrac{1}{1+a/x}\right)dt\\
&=\int_0^{\frac{a}{x}}\left(\dfrac{(1+a/x)-(1+t)}{(1+t)(1+a/x)}\right)dt\\
&=\int_0^{\frac{a}{x}}\left(\dfrac{a/x-t}{(1+t)(1+a/x)}\right)dt\\
&\ge 0
\qquad\text{since } \frac{a}{x} \ge t\\
\end{array}
$